# Can different waveforms be used for injection and recovery in bilby?

Tags: bilby

Is it possible to inject a signal with waveform A and then recover it with a different waveform?

*Question asked by Nirban Bose on the bilby slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a good example of this is the [Reduced Order Quadrature example](https://git.ligo.org/lscsoft/bilby/blob/master/examples/injection_examples/roq_example.py). The key is to generate the data with a different `waveform_generator` to the one used in the search. Practically, this amounts to passing a different `waveform_generator` to the `interferometer` data generated and to the `likelihood`.

Here is a pseudo code demonstration which injects a binary black hole and recovers a binary neutron star waveform

```py
# Make some injection parameters
injection_parameters = dict(
    chirp_mass=36., mass_ratio=0.9, a_1=0.4, a_2=0.3, tilt_1=0.0, tilt_2=0.0,
    phi_12=1.7, phi_jl=0.3, luminosity_distance=1000., iota=0.4, psi=0.659,
    phase=1.3, geocent_time=1126259642.413, ra=1.375, dec=-1.2108)

# Make the injection waveform generator
waveform_arguments = dict(waveform_approximant='IMRPhenomPv2',
                          reference_frequency=20., minimum_frequency=20.)
injection_waveform_generator = bilby.gw.WaveformGenerator(
    duration=duration, sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency,
    frequency_domain_source_model=bilby.gw.source.lal_binary_black_hole,
    waveform_arguments=waveform_arguments)

# Setup the interferometer list
ifos = bilby.gw.detector.InterferometerList(['H1', 'L1', 'V1'])
ifos.set_strain_data_from_power_spectral_densities(
    sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency, duration=duration,
    start_time=injection_parameters['geocent_time'] - 3)

# Here we inject a signal using the injection_waveform_generator
ifos.inject_signal(waveform_generator=injection_waveform_generator,
                   parameters=injection_parameters)


# Now create a search waveform generator (i.e. the one used for PE)
# Here you can specify anything you like, e.g. a different waveform approximant,
# in this example, I've just used a binary neutron star instead
waveform_arguments = dict(waveform_approximant='IMRPhenomPv2',
                          reference_frequency=20., minimum_frequency=20.)
search_waveform_generator = bilby.gw.WaveformGenerator(
    duration=duration, sampling_frequency=sampling_frequency,
    frequency_domain_source_model=bilby.gw.source.lal_binary_neutron_star,
    waveform_arguments=waveform_arguments)

# Set up your priors
priors = ...

# Now set up the likelihood - here we pass in the search waveform generator
likelihood = bilby.gw.likelihood.GravitationalWaveTransient(
    interferometers=ifos, waveform_generator=search_waveform_generator,
    prior=priors)

# Run the sampler
result = bilby.run_sampler(
    likelihood=likelihood, priors=priors, ...)
```

This should be adaptable to a good number of situations.